# Angular: Two FormControl inside one mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `mat-form-field` with a `mat-select` in it. This works as expected. The `mat-form-field` is with `appearance="outline"`. Now I want to add a second component `apm-lock` inside the outline that displays an icon to lock or unlock.

```html
<mat-form-field class='block' appearance="outline">
      <mat-label i18n>Anlagenbetreiber Objektgruppe</mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple formControlName="value" required>
        <mat-option>
          <ngx-mat-select-search apmSelectSearchFilter [formControl]="plantOperatorObjectFilterCtrl"
            [data]="filteredplantOperatorsObject" [fields]="['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']">
          </ngx-mat-select-search>
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredplantOperatorsObject | async" [value]="user._id">
          {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}} ({{user.email}})</mat-option>
      </mat-select>

      <apm-lock formControlName="locked"></apm-lock>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I can see the lock and click it, this changes the state of the lock, but also opens the `mat-select`. How can I make sure that the select doesn't open, when I click the icon?

Also, the Icon is displayed under the `mat-select`. How can I display this on the right of the `mat-select`?

[image: mat-select and icon inside mat-form-field]

Edit:

After putting the apm-lock before (important, but don't know why...) the `mat-select` and added `matSuffix` to it, the lock appears behind the `mat-select`.

```html
<mat-form-field class='block' appearance="outline">
      <mat-label i18n>Anlagenbetreiber Objektgruppe</mat-label>

      <apm-lock matSuffix formControlName="locked"></apm-lock>

      <mat-select multiple formControlName="value" required>
        <mat-option>
          <ngx-mat-select-search apmSelectSearchFilter [formControl]="plantOperatorObjectFilterCtrl"
            [data]="filteredplantOperatorsObject" [fields]="['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']">
          </ngx-mat-select-search>
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredplantOperatorsObject | async" [value]="user._id">
          {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}} ({{user.email}})</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image: component with matSuffix]

The only issue now is, that the select opens on clicking on the component. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Instead of nesting them inside one another, try creating a parent div which wraps them, and then position the child elements according to your wishes?

Comment: @MikkelChristensen That is not an issue, but then the lock is outside the outline border, but I want it inside the border.

Comment: Have you tried to use `$event.stopPropagation()` in the (click) function of the icon ?

Comment: @archelite Thanks, I have tried this on the `apm-lock` component `<apm-lock matSuffix formControlName="locked" matTooltip="Für Import sperren" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></apm-lock>`, but that doesn't change the behaviour. The `apm-lock` is a separate module in a private npm package. The component displays one of two icons depending on the state of the locked input of the component.

Comment: @archelite ok, seems my dev server had some issues, after restarting the server, the `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on `apm-lock` worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @archelite, I could fix this with `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` on `apm-lock`.

```html
<mat-form-field class='block' appearance="outline">
      <mat-label i18n>Anlagenverantwortlicher</mat-label>

      <apm-lock matSuffix formControlName="locked" matTooltip="Für Import sperren" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></apm-lock>

      <mat-select multiple formControlName="value">
        <mat-option>
          <ngx-mat-select-search apmSelectSearchFilter [formControl]="plantResponsibleFilterCtrl"
            [data]="filteredplantResponsibles" [fields]="['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']">
          </ngx-mat-select-search>
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredplantResponsibles | async" [value]="user._id">
          {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}} ({{user.email}})</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```